# How to specify custom Istio ingress gateway in Kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, ingress-controller

I deployed Istio [using the operator](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/) and added a custom ingress gateway which is only accessible from a certain source range (our VPN).

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: ground-zero-ingressgateway
spec:
  profile: empty
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
      - name: istio-vpn-ingressgateway
        label:
          app: istio-vpn-ingressgateway
          istio: vpn-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          serviceAnnotations:
            ...
          service:
            loadBalancerSourceRanges:
              - "x.x.x.x/x"
```

Now I want to configure Istio to expose a service outside of the service mesh cluster, using the [Kubernetes Ingress resource](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/). I use the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation to tell the Istio gateway controller that it should handle this `Ingress`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio
spec:
   ...
```

- Kubernetes version (EKS): 1.19
- Istio version: 1.10.3

Which ingress gateway controller is now used (`istio-ingressgateway` or `istio-vpn-ingressgateway`)? Is there a way to specify which one should be used?

P.S. I know that I could create a `VirtualService` and specify the correct gateway but we want to write a manifest that also works without Istio by specifying the correct ingress controller with an annotation.

Comment: Which verion of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you deploy it? Did you use bare metal or cloud provider?

Comment: I added the information to the question.

Comment: why would you want to access your cluster through `Ingress` instead of the gateway?

Comment: I want to access the cluster through the gateway but I want to avoid a `VirtualService` and use an `Ingress` instead.

Comment: Did you see [this example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/)?

Comment: Yes, but this page does only considers the case when you have one ingress gateway.

Comment: You are using the [deprecated annotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation). Did you try to specify `IngressClass` as in [this example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/#specifying-ingressclass)?

Comment: Yes, I also tried that example but it does not describe how to specify the ingress controller if there are multiple Istio ingress gateways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an ingress class that references the ingress controller that is deployed by default in the istio-system namespace. This configuration with ingress will work, however to my current knowledge, this is only used for backwards compatibility. If you want to use [istio ingress](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/) controller functionality, you should use istio gateway and virtual service instead:

> Using the [Istio Gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/), rather than Ingress, is recommended to make use of the full feature set that Istio offers, such as rich traffic management and security features.

If this solution is not optimal for you, you should use e.g. [nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) and you can still bind it with [annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/) (deprecated) or using `IngressClass`. To my present knowledge **it is not possible to bind this ingress class with an additional ingress controller.** If you need an explanation, documentation, you should create an [issue on github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues).

**Summary:** The recommended option is to use the gateway with virtual service. Another possibility is to use nginx alone ingress with different classes and an ingress resource for them.